# Dealing with encodings in sqlite library

Tags: r, sqlite, encoding, sas

I'm reading a dataset I stored in an sqlite3 database in R in SAS. I am able to read the dataset but all character Variables have encoding errors. What I tried so far:

- OEMCPTranslation option of the ODBC Driver
- converting the Encoding before writing the table. (I guess this should have no effect, because RSQLite should convert it to UTF-8 anyway.)
- The INENCODING option of libname, which is not implemented for ODBC libraries
- There should be INECNDOING and OUTENCODING options for the copy statement, but I did not find any documentation so I did not get the syntax right.

My system encoding is latin1. I'm on a Windows machine with SAS 9.4.

```
libname sqlite odbc complete="dsn=SQLite3 Datasource; Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver}; Database=C:\path\to\library.sqlite; OEMCPTranslation=1";

libname mylib "C:\path\to\SASLibrary";

proc datasets library=sqlite;
    copy out=mylib;
run;
```

Comment: Have you tried running a SAS session in the proper system encoding (UTF-8 or whatever)?

Comment: I got it to work. Obviously it was a syntax error in SAS/ODBC, the OEMCPTranslation option was not honoured. Connecting manually works.